# CKEditor is not working while editing CiviCRM

Tags: drupal, civicrm-home, civicrm.settings.php, ckeditor, civicrm-event

While I am trying to add/edit the CiviCRM events, instead of CKEditor, the default textarea is displaying and also the HTML tags are display. But the CKEditor is working as expected for the Drupal contents.

I have checked on the Browser Console and I saw an error. The JS file URL is missing the actual domain, instead it takes the CiviCRM path.

> GET https://sites/all/modules/civicrm/js/wysiwyg/crm.ckeditor.js?r=ufXP1 net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
>
> Please check the Image link for more details - https://ibb.co/Nr4DcX4

**CiviCRM 5.26.1

Drupal 7**

I doubt this is something related to the paths and URL configuration. Please let me know if you require any more details to investigate this issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your civicrm root set in civicrm.settings.php and drupal directory path set in nginx or apache

Comment: How is this question different from your deleted question here? https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/35846/ckeditor-is-not-working-while-editing-civicrm

Comment: $civicrm_root = SITE_DIR . '/sites/all/modules/civicrm/';
civicrm root set in civicrm.settings.php

Comment: Thanks for your help. Its working. I have missed to add the '/' on $civicrm_root = SITE_DIR . 'sites/all/modules/civicrm/'. Once I have added '/' on $civicrm_root = SITE_DIR . '/sites/all/modules/civicrm/', the CKEditor has been started working.